# how to set active class using ui-router when children state is active

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, children

I have sidebar with some items in menu. this is the code of sidebar

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
        <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
            <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.home"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</md-button>
        </li>
       <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
            <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.userManagement"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>  User </md-button>
        </li>
        <li  ui-sref-active-eq="sideActive" >
            <md-button ng-click="check(4)"  class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.manage"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>  Order Management<span class="fa arrow"></span></md-button>
            <ul class="orderNav nav nav-second-level" collapse="collapseVar!=4">
                <li ng-class="{orderActive: $state.includes('order_management')}">
                    <md-button width="2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.manage" class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2">Manage Orders</md-button>
                </li>
                <li  ng-class="{orderActive: $state.includes('order_management')}">
                    <md-button width="2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.payment.transfers" class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2">Payment</md-button>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
            <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.artManagement"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>  Art Management</md-button>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
```

in the above code, for the order management, there are sub menu items,and in that sub menu items, for one of the sub item, there are another sub items(which will show in main view rather than side bar).
for example: say in 1)order management-->I) Payment II)Refund
                                                |
                                        i)transfers ii)revenue
when view is in revenue or transfers or payment, the order management should be active.i am getting url `http://localhost:8080/admin/#/dashboard/order_management/payment/transfer` like this for transfer. but for those buttons i am not able set active class,when transfers is clicked.
this is one of the state code.

```
.state('dashboard.orderManagement.manage', {
            templateUrl: 'submodules/order_management/manageOrder.html',
            url: '/manage_order',
            controller: 'orderCtrl',
            resolve: {
                loadMyFiles: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'abcd',
                        files: [
                            'submodules/order_management/controller.js',
                            'scripts/services.js'
                        ]
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```

How to do it , can anyone please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are giving wrong state in ng-class attribute of sub element of the list. Try using below code.

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
                <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
                    <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.home"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</md-button>
                </li>
               <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
                    <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.userManagement"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>  User </md-button>
                </li>
                <li  ng-class="{orderActive: $state.includes('dashboard.orderManagement')}" >
                    <md-button ng-click="check(4)"  class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.manage"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>  Order Management<span class="fa arrow"></span></md-button>
                    <ul class="orderNav nav nav-second-level" collapse="collapseVar!=4">
                        <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
                            <md-button width="2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.manage" class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2">Manage Orders</md-button>
                        </li>
                        <li  ui-sref-active="sideActive">
                            <md-button width="2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.payment.transfers" class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2">Payment</md-button>
                        </li>
                        <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
                            <md-button width="2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.pixum" class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2">Pixum</md-button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
                    <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.artManagement"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>  Art Management</md-button>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Controller code:

```
 $stateProvider.state('dashboard.orderManagement', {
              url: '/order_management',
              abstract: true,
              template: '<div ui-view></div>'
            })
            .state('dashboard.orderManagement.manage', {
             templateUrl: 'submodules/order_management/manageOrder.html',
            url: '/manage_order',
            controller: 'orderCtrl',
            resolve: {
                loadMyFiles: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'artifuAdmin',
                        files: [
                            'submodules/order_management/controller.js',
                            'scripts/services.js'
                        ]
                    })
                }
            }
            })
            .state('dashboard.orderManagement.pixum', {
               //content
            });
```

Comment: i have used same thing, but  i interchanged the class name from your code, it is not working as i expected. if i don't have ui-sref-active in sub items, it will be active, but not when there is separate active class for sub menu items

Comment: Its working for me, have you set abstract: true in your state ''dashboard.orderManagement'? Also, Try using ng-class="{sideActive: $state.includes('dashboard.orderManagement')}"  rather than ng-class="{orderActive: $state.includes('dashboard.orderManagement')}"

Comment: i have used the same thing, as i needed the sideActive class for the parent. and i didn't used any abstract:true here. please check the question, i post routing code too

Comment: if i add ui-sref-active along with ng-class like this `<li ng-class="{sideActive: $state.includes('dashboard.orderManagement')}" ui-sref-active="sideActive"> ` it will be active when it is clicked.  i know ui-sref-active is not necessary when i used ng-class like that. but i tried

Comment: you have used `,` for your last edit code (5th line of controller code ) `dashboard.orderManagement,manage`

Comment: Still not adding any class into it. please see  my screenshot above

Comment: Can you please tell me, what is my mistake again here

Answer (score 1):

Using of filter to add class solved my issue. 
   Example:`<li ng-class="{sideActive: ('dashboard.orderManagement' | includedByState)}" >`

```
<ul class="nav in" id="side-menu">
            <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
                <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.home"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</md-button>
            </li>
           <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
                <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.userManagement"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>  User Management</md-button>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{sideActive: ('dashboard.orderManagement' | includedByState)}" >
                <md-button ng-click="check(4)"  class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.manage"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>  Order Management<span class="fa arrow"></span></md-button>
                <ul class="orderNav nav nav-second-level" collapse="collapseVar!=4">
                    <li ui-sref-active="orderActive">
                        <md-button width="2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.manage" class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2">Manage Orders</md-button>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-class="{orderActive: ('dashboard.orderManagement.payment' | includedByState)}">
                        <md-button width="2" ui-sref="dashboard.orderManagement.payment.transfers" class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2">Payment</md-button>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="sideActive">
                <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" ui-sref="dashboard.artManagement"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>  Art Management</md-button>
            </li>

        </ul>
```